# Scala 2.12.0: output of assigning a function literal to a value

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.12.0, the output is something like `$$Lambda` when assign a function literal to a value, while in 2.11.8, it will be `<functionX>`. Why there is such a change ? Does `$$Lambda` mean a lambda expression here ?

2.12.0:

```
scala> val doubler = (x: Int) => x * 2
doubler: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1276/486758400@52f8f398
```

2.11.8:

```
scala> val doubler = (x: Int) => x * 2
doubler: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Java platform, the Scala 2.12 compiler uses the same encoding for anonymous functions that the Java 8+ compiler uses. So, the difference you are seeing is basically that in the first case, you are seeing the output of the `toString()` method from a Scala `Function1[Int, Int]` instance, whereas in the second case, you are seeing the `toString()` of a Java 8 Lambda.

Note, however, that this is a private internal implementation detail of the Scala-JVM compiler. You should *not* rely on it. It might be, and probably *is* different on Scala.js and Scala-native.