# Why my function on Scala REPL is print as 'Lambda'?

Tags: scala, scala-repl

I created this function on Scala REPL

```
scala> val multiDouble = (input :Double) =>
 |      {
 |          val toMulti = 2;
 |          toMulti * input 
 |      }: Double
```

And the output is `val multiDouble: Double => Double = Lambda$1351/1709493124@7b44bfb8`

For what I've studied it should be `val multiDouble: Double => Double = <function01>`

I don't understand why Scala REPL prints `Lambda$1351/1709493124@7b44bfb8` and not `<function01>`.

Comment: From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983941/viewing-the-contents-in-function1-from-the-scala-repl

Comment: My version is Scala 3.2.2

Comment: Is then Lambda$1351/1709493124@7b44bfb8 the base68 identifier of my function in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala 2.11- functions are printed as `<function01>`, in Scala 2.12+ they are printed as `Lambda$.../...@...`

*2.12 lambdas have different `toString`* https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/67

> @retronym:
>
> It is unavoidable if we use `LambdaMetaFactory`, which doesn't expose a way to provide an implementation of `toString`. (Default methods in interfaces themselves can't override methods in Object, either).
>
> We could provide `ScalaLambdaMetafactory` to generate precisely what we want, but the risk is that we will forgo current or future optimizations in HotSpot targetting LMF.

[Scala 2.12.0: output of assigning a function literal to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872120/scala-2-12-0-output-of-assigning-a-function-literal-to-a-value)

[datatype of anonymous function vs named function in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921238/datatype-of-anonymous-function-vs-named-function-in-scala)

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/functionns-tostring-should-show-the-types/2572